# How do I use function 1 inside function 2 without getting an error?

Tags: python, function-call

I declared the `view_songs()` function which I want to use separately and I also want to use it inside another function `add_songs()` with a conditional, after the code which does the part of adding songs to the collection.

```
user_input = input('Enter "a" to add songs,"f" to find existing songs,"v" to view entire collection and "q" to quit :')

while user_input != "q":

    if user_input == "v":

        def view_songs():
            for song in enumerate(Songs_collection, 1):
                print(song)
        view_songs()

    elif user_input == "a":

        def add_songs():
            elements_in_list = len(Songs_collection)
            song_name = input('Enter the name of the song to be added to the collection: ')
            song_artist = input('Enter the name of the artist of the song which was added previously :')
            Songs_collection.insert(elements_in_list, ({elements_in_list + 101: f'{song_name}', f'{elements_in_list + 101}_Artist': f'{song_artist}'}))
            print('Song added to the collection!')
            post_add_input = input('Press "v" to print whole collection or "q" to quit:')
            if post_add_input == "v":
                view_songs()
            elif post_add_input == "q":
                print('Quitting loop...')
            else:
                print('Invalid Input')

        add_songs()
```

It gives me an error which says `free variable view_songs referenced before assignment in the enclosing scope`. How can I go about to using this function inside `add_Songs()`?

Comment: What if the user selection is found to be `"a"` before `"v"`? This would mean the definition of `add_songs` is called before we ever create the `view_songs` function.

My suggestion would be to simply bring the definition of the two functions outside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above this should hopefully solve the issues you're having?

```
def view_songs():
            for song in enumerate(Songs_collection, 1):
                print(song)

def add_songs():
            elements_in_list = len(Songs_collection)
            song_name = input('Enter the name of the song to be added to the collection: ')
            song_artist = input('Enter the name of the artist of the song which was added previously :')
            Songs_collection.insert(elements_in_list, ({elements_in_list + 101: f'{song_name}', f'{elements_in_list + 101}_Artist': f'{song_artist}'}))
            print('Song added to the collection!')
            post_add_input = input('Press "v" to print whole collection or "q" to quit:')
            if post_add_input == "v":
                view_songs()
            elif post_add_input == "q":
                print('Quitting loop...')
            else:
                print('Invalid Input')

while user_input != "q":
    if user_input == "v":
        view_songs()
    elif user_input == "a":
        add_songs()

    #Some way to redefine user_input?
    #user_input = input()
```

Comment: Hey, I moved the function definitions outside the while loop and ran the loop with only the execution statements and now it works fine! Thanks!

Comment: Remember to check the tick below the upvote/downvote counter :)